# Windows Server 2008 Remote/FTP Backup

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, ftp

I'm using Windows Server 2008, and have the requirement to backup system state and data to a remote location.

What's the best way to do this, unfortunately it appears Windows Server Backup doesn't allow this, and I'm not usually a fan of 3rd party backup software as if the need to restore it arises I'm of the opinion it's more difficult to restore.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Symantec System Recovery 2011](http://www.symantec.com/system-recovery-server-edition) will do this.  It allows you to FTP a backup job offsite .  Lots of other features as well.  We use it for bare metal recovery and it works very well.  Demo is available I believe.

Answer (score 1):

If you're against using 3rd party software to copy these backups, why not use [WinSCP and script something](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) that copies your backup files from your local server to your remote server.

This is by no means the fastest way of getting copies of data offsite, but it will work without 3rd party backup software. In addition to Symantec System Recovery (mentioned by Dave M), [Acronis Backup & Recovery](http://www.acronis.com/backup-recovery/smallbusiness.html) will also allow you to backup to a remote site should you decide to go with a third party piece of software.